# Get rid of the header on the first page of the chapter

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I try to write my document with both the headers and the foots, but the headers should not appear on the first page of the chapter and there should be no line in the header by the chapter*. How can I reach this? I also would like to remove the word "chapter" from the header. This is my minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no line in header area
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}           % page number in "outer" position of footer line
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\today} % other info in "inner" position of footer line
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}           % page number in "outer" position of footer line
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\today} % other info in "inner" position of footer line
}
\begin{document}

\chapter*{Contents} 

\chapter{Introduction}

This is the first section.

Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing  
elit.   Etiam  lobortisfacilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et 
neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. 
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales...

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}` command replaces the normal plain pagestyle (first page of chapter) with a fancy pagestyle.  Just remove it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no line in header area
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}           % page number in "outer" position of footer line
\fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\today} % other info in "inner" position of footer line

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Contents} 

\chapter{Introduction}

This is the first section.

Lorem  ipsum  dolor  sit  amet,  consectetuer  adipiscing  
elit.   Etiam  lobortisfacilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et 
neque pharetra sollicitudin.  Praesent imperdietmi nec ante. 
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales...

\end{document}
```